# SQL count without wrapping query

Tags: sql

I have the following hypothetical code and it works for getting the number of rows of `site`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT site
      FROM (SELECT...) x
 LEFT JOIN foo.bars 
        ON foo.id = x.id
  GROUP BY site
)
```

Is there any other way to do this count without using the outer most SELECT?

Comment: Is there any point to the LEFT JOIN here? As it doesn't restrict anything and you're making your result-set unique it would appear to be unnecessary.

Comment: please describe, what do you want to get, `SELECT a FROM whatever GROUP BY a` has the same effect as `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM whatever`

Comment: maybe you wanted `SELECT site, count(*) FROM ... GROUP BY site`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you want with `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT site)
FROM (SELECT...) x LEFT JOIN
     foo.bars 
     ON foo.id = x.id;
```

The one difference is that the original version will count a `NULL` value of `site`.  If this is important, then the query can be easily modified to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion doesn't include a `GROUP BY`, though, like my original query did. What I get when I add `COUNT(DISTINCT site)` to my query is a list of all the rows, with a count of `1` next each row, which is of course not what I'm after. Is there a way to make this work when a `GROUP BY` is present?

Comment: @OlalekanSogunle he only simplified your SELECT statement, `DISTINCT site` replaces your `GROUP BY site`

Comment: Never mind, we could just remove the group by. thanks @PavelGatnar